# Alternatives to ANCOVA when assumptions are violated

Tags: heteroscedasticity, ancova, assumptions

I am doing research on organisational change and looking at how certain types of change (e.g. closures of offices, layoffs, investment on activities/functions) have affected seven psychological variables (commitment, trust in leaders, procedural fairness, perception of organisational support, etc.).

Now, I want to know how the changes (related to the types of organisational change described above) in the content of the psychological contract (measured through four of the psychological variables) impact organisational commitment (if at all). My original idea was to run an analysis of covariance in SPSS, but in checking for the basic assumptions I found that the regression slopes are not homogeneous, and that is the end of ANCOVA according to several authors.

I am left without a clear idea of how to circumvent this problem. What kind of analysis can be performed when:

1. The covariates and the factor (type of change) are related, and
2. The regression slopes are not homogeneous?

Please, bear in mind that mine is NOT an experimental design, rather observational, change happens without my intervention and I just look at an internal survey that studies the psychological and demographic variables.

Comment: How many measurements have you got? That is, is this a single observation or did you measure the variables more than once?

Comment: Your problem is use of the term 'ANCOVA'.  Substitute for it 'multivariable regression model' and everything is OK, including modeling interactions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies Peter and Frank. I have a single observation, that is I analyse change in 2007-2008 and the psychological variables were measured in 2008. I will analyse the same in 2010 but the groups differ so there will not be the same individuals in both years.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: could I use the same command on SPSS (Unianova) specifying in the 'design' command the interactions between event and the variables? I want to be able to do special contrasts and I find it easier this way than using the standard regression command. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know SPSS.  This is trivial in R.